# How to import scala class automatically in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala

I use eclipse as my scala ide. And I know that in java I can use short cut by content assistent to import classes. So I do not need type in the whole class name. Just need to type the first several characters.

But in scala, I can not import classes automatically. Do I need to do some set up or it is just because scala plugin do not support this.

Comment: As the Scala IDE is still in beta, this question is best asked on the [Scala IDE mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user/topics?start=). The problem may be temporary. Voting to close as too localized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Scala IDE for Eclipse](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide) however it is not very mature these days, however improving day by day. As far as I remember it can import automatically, or you can use Eclipse global fix import hotkey ctrl+shift+o.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

on symbol works for me :)